# Calculate the expected value of the following random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, variance

a) In a horserace, W denotes the winnings. The probability of winning 5USD is 0.02, the one for winning 25USD is 0.002 and the one for winning 100USD is 0.0005 (the probability of not winning any money is 0.9775).

**For this part I got $E= \frac 1 5$**

b)The random variable X has the pdf f : R→R
$$
f(x) :=
\begin{cases}
\frac{4x(9-x^2)}{81},  & \text{for $0\le x\le3$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

**I got$ E=1$ here after integration**

c) For the random variable Y it remains that
$$
P[Y=y] :=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}^y,  & \text{for $y\in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$} \\
c, & \text{for $y=6$} \\
\end{cases}
$$
with a value of c so that $\sum_y P[Y=y] = 1$ is reached

***I am uncertain on how to start with this one, how do I find c and how do I integrate this?***

d) The random var. z has a pdf g : R→R 
$$
g(z) :=
\begin{cases}
\frac {10}{9z^2},  & \text{for $1\le z\le10$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

**For this part I also got $E=1$**

Did you get the same answers as me?  I'm not sure if I'm doing it right so I would appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a). is correct, but b). and d). are wrong. You need to compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)dx$ to get the expected value, **not** $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx$ (which is *always* equal to $1$ by definition since $f$ is a probability density function). Same for d).

As for c). you must have that the sum of probabilities is $1$. Therefore,
$$
1 = \sum_{k=1}^6 \Pr[Y=k] = \sum_{k=1}^5 \frac{1}{2^k}+ c
$$
which allows you to find $c$ (check that $c\geq 0$, to make sure you did not nake an obvious mistake). Once you have $c$, you can get the expected value as
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{k=1}^6 k\Pr[Y=k] = \sum_{k=1}^5 \frac{k}{2^k}+  6c\,.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by $xf(x)$? Like for b) do I multiply it with x=0, 1, 2, 3?

Comment: You have the density function $f$ for $Y$. Since $f$ is a density, this means $f\geq 0$, and $\int f(x) dx = 1$. To compute $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, you integrate $x\cdot f(x)$, i.e. $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int x\cdot f(x) dx$$ (the same way that, for discrete random variables, you  have$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{k} k\cdot \Pr[Y=k]$$ the sum and integral play "analogous" role here)

Comment: @Rocca For instance, for d)., you should compute $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)dx = \int_1^{10} x\cdot \frac{10}{9x^2} dx = \frac{10}{9}\int_1^{10} \frac{dx}{x}\,.$$

Comment: Aha now I get it! Thanks!

Comment: @Rocca You're welcome!